# how to use variable that declared in classname.m to that particular classnameviewcontroller.m

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone development. what i did is i am creating a class named imagepicker.h along with imagepicker.m,for that classes i am creating imagepickerviewcontroller.h and imagepickerviewcontroller.m.... in the imagepicker.m i am declring a button for that button assing a image tag value. "now what i need is how to get that buttion.tag value to imagepickerviewcontroller.m" please help me thanku

Answer (score 0):

Declare the button in your imagepicker.h, make it a property and access it in you view controller by creating an object ob imagepicker class. `imagepickerobject.button.tag`